# .htaccess 301 Redirect (old url to new update) with php get query

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect a few old URLs to new ones using htaccess, which rewrites a GET query in my PHP file to clean URLs:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch 301 /photo/old-photo /photo/new-photo    
RewriteRule ^photo/(.*)/?$ tpl-photo.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^photo/(.*)?$ tpl-photo.php?slug=$1
```

This outputs my clean URLs correctly like so:

```
http://website.com/photo/one-beautiful-photo
```

However, when I try to redirect my old URLs to new URLs, it somehow messes up the URL:

```
http://website.com/photo/new-photo?slug=old-photo
```

How can I correct this so that I get a proper clean new URL:

```
http://website.com/photo/new-photo
```

Comment: Post your complete `.htaccess` and if your old URL have a querystring post a better example illustrating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` and `mod_rewrite` rules and keep only `mod_rewrite` rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^photo/old-photo/?$ /photo/new-photo [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^photo/([^/]+)/?$ tpl-photo.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```